# Invalidating certain date/times with Date Range Picker?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using a JavaScript plugin called Date Range Picker (link: http://www.daterangepicker.com) - I am building a reservation system so I am using the date picker and the time picker as well. My code looks like this:

```
$(function() {

    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
    var nextyear=new Date();
    nextyear.setFullYear(nextyear.getFullYear()+1);

  $('input[name="car-rental-pickup-date"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      minDate: tomorrow,
      maxDate: nextyear,
      singleDatePicker: true,
      timePicker: true,
      timePickerIncrement: 30,
      autoApply: true,
      linkedCalendars: false,
      showCustomRangeLabel: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      },
  });

  $('input[name="car-rental-pickup-date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      document.getElementById("car-rental-pickup-date").value = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      document.getElementById("car-rental-pickup-time").value = picker.startDate.format('h:mm A');
      getpricing();

  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
```

My business only allows for pickups Monday - Friday from 9am - 4:30pm and Saturday and on Sundays 9am - 11:30am. So what I think to do is use the isInvalidDate function.

If I use this function I can successfully block out a day like this (blocks out Sept 15th 2019):

```
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
        if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '2019-09-15') {
            return true; 
        }
```

But when I try to block out all Sundays with this method, like this:

```
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
        if (today.getDay() == 0) {
            return true; 
        }
```

It does not work. Could someone please assist me on this problem? Also how would I go about incorporating blacking out the time? I didn't see any documentation for that.

Comment: Shouldn't `today.getDay()` in your last example be `date.getDay()`?

Comment: Hi @Mike - I don't think so, the 2nd line of code is:     var today = new Date(); so that is correct... I think.

Comment: That references what would be the current date and not the date the user puts into your widget.

You're previous example uses `date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '2019-09-15')` and not `today.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '2019-09-15')`

Comment: Okay, then how would you suggest I block out all Sundays and do the time?

Comment: I just had a quick gander at the library's source and I don't think you'll be able to disable times on dates. You can disable dates (e.g. make users unable to select Sundays) but you won't be able to limit the time users can pick.

Comment: Man, that is pretty terrible for me. Would you recommend any date pickers that I will be able to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately not off the top of my head I'd need to do some research. I wish I could offer you a tip but best of luck.

As an aside you'd almost certainly want data like that to be validated server-side and not only on the client. If you get a malicious user and didn't have the correct validation in place they could spam your back-end with improper data.

Comment: Oh yes, most definitely - good thing for me I am better at PHP than I am at Javascript!